# Pairwise plot across two consistent dataframes?

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, plot, scatter-plot

I have two data frames (164 observations across 5766 variables). One dataframe, Scores, has a number between 0-1 for each observation (date) and each variable (company). The other is called Returns, and has a number number between -1 and 10 for each observation (date) and each variable (company). I am trying to make a scatter plot of every (Scores, Returns) pair for each date and company. The data sets are 1:1 matched (i.e. there are no gaps in either).

Currently I am trying to generate the pairs to feed into plot. Right now I have:

```
Scores<-read.csv("~/Scores.csv")
Returns<-read.csv("~/Returns.csv")
head(Scores)
# A tibble: 6 x 5,766
  `C-DATE`    C1    C2    C3    C4    C5    C6    C7    C8    C9   C10
     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1        1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
2        2     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
3        3     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
4        4     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
5        5     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
6        6     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 head(Returns)
# A tibble: 6 x 5,766
  `C-DATE`    C1    C2    C3    C4    C5    C6    C7    C8    C9   C10
     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1        1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
2        2     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
3        3     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
4        4     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
5        5     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
6        6     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

I am then making an empty matrix of the same size as these two dataframes,and trying to write the pair c(Scores, Returns) to each instance on the matrix:

```
plotpairs<-matrix(nrow=nrow(Scores),ncol=ncol(Scores))
for(j in 1:nrow(plotpairs)){
  for(k in 1:ncol(plotpairs)){
    plotpairs[j,k]<-c(Scores[j,k],Returns[j,k])
  }
}
```

This returns the following error:

```
Error in vectors[j, k] <- c(Scores[j, k], Returns[j, k]) : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

What is causing this to fail given that these are all of equal size, and ***is there an easier way to generate a pairwise scatterplot across two dataframes?***

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you start with these two tables:

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1)

df1 <- 
  tibble(
    date = 1:6, 
    C1 = rnorm(6), 
    C2 = rnorm(6)
  )
df2 <- 
  tibble(
    date = 1:6, 
    C1 = rnorm(6), 
    C2 = rnorm(6)
  )

df1
   date     C1     C2
  <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1 -0.626  0.487
2     2  0.184  0.738
3     3 -0.836  0.576
4     4  1.60  -0.305
5     5  0.330  1.51 
6     6 -0.820  0.390

df2
# A tibble: 6 x 3
   date      C1      C2
  <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1     1 -0.621   0.821 
2     2 -2.21    0.594 
3     3  1.12    0.919 
4     4 -0.0449  0.782 
5     5 -0.0162  0.0746
6     6  0.944  -1.99
```

One way you could avoid the loop is to gather the points into a long format, where one data frame represents the X values and has unique rows for C-DATE and C#, with another data frame representing the Y values, followed by a join on the C-DATE and C# pair:

```
df_joined <- 
  df1 %>% 
  gather(key = key, value = x, C1:C2) %>% 
  left_join(
    df2 %>% gather(key = key, value = y, C1:C2),
    by = c("date", "key")
  ) 

df_joined
    date key        x       y
   <int> <chr>  <dbl>   <dbl>
 1     1 C1    -0.626 -0.621 
 2     2 C1     0.184 -2.21  
...
```

Then you can pass that into ggplot to show the pairs:

```
ggplot(df_joined, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point()
```

Comment: I have taken @cardinal40 advice and now have the following: `set.seed(1)

companies<-vector()
comapnies<-for(i in 1:5765){
  companies[i]<-paste("C",toString(i),sep="")
}

df1 <- Scores
df2 <- Returns

df_joined <- 
  df1 %>% 
  gather(key="key", value=x, comapnies) %>%
  left_join(
    df2 %>% gather(key="key", value = y,comapnies),
    by = c("C-DATE","key")
  )

ggplot(dj_joined, aes(x=x, y=y))+geom_point()`   Which returns the following error: `'by' can't contain join column 'key' which is missing from LHS` Any idea what I am missing?